# Can one not overload methods that just take a function (of different types) as parameter?

Tags: scala, overloading, type-erasure

I have a method:

```
def udf(func: RDD[Row] => RDD[Row]) = ...
```

and another method:

```
def udf(func: List[String] => List[String]) = ...
```

in Scala. And it gives me this:

```
Error:(...) double definition:
method udf:(func: List[String] => List[String])UDFOperator and
method udf:(func: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Row] => org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Row])UDFOperator at ...
have same type after erasure: (func: Function1)UDFOperator
  def udf(func: List[String] => List[String]) = {
      ^
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The JVM doesn't support generics, so anything that Scala might need in order to resolve a runtime generic type check can't be done.

In your case, both methods are expecting `Function1[_,_]` parameters, and the JVM can't tell the difference between them.  You'll have to rename one of them.

Comment: Ok, so I just tried `def s(a: List[Int]) = a.size` & `def s(a: List[String]) = a` also doesn't work. It makes sense. If I had to do same things there, I could do `def s[T](a: List[T]) = a.size`.